# Не работают сигналы и слоты в pyqt

Tags: qt, python-2.x, pyqt4

```
# -*- coding: 1251 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def EnterPressed():
    print("blabla")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ptxt1 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    ptxt2 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    ptxt3 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    QtCore.QObject.connect(ptxt1, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), ptxt2, QtCore.SLOT("EnterPressed()"))
    spl1=QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    spl2=QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,spl1)
    spl1.addWidget(ptxt1)
    spl2.addWidget(ptxt2)
    spl2.addWidget(ptxt3)

    spl1.resize(500, 500)
    spl1.show()
    spl2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Прошу объяснить, почему вызов слота не работает.

Comment: как вы определяете, что не работает?

Comment: Если фокус на ptxt1 и нажимается Enter то в консоли должно быть напечатано "blabla".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте предупреждения в консоли во время выполнения вашей программы.

Написано же:

> Object::connect: No such slot QTextEdit::EnterPressed()

Вы попытались подключить сигнал к слоту, которого не существует.

Да, и кроме того, класс `QTextEdit`, который вы используете не имеет сигнала `returnPressed()`. Этот сигнал есть у класса `QLineEdit`, к примеру. [Ссылка на документацию](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#signals).

**Исправил ваш пример, используя `QLineEdit`:**

```
class Test(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def EnterPressed(self):
        print("blabla")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ptxt1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    ptxt2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    ptxt3 = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    ptxt1.setText("1")
    ptxt2.setText("2")
    ptxt3.setText("3")

    tst = Test()
    QtCore.QObject.connect(ptxt1, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), tst, QtCore.SLOT("EnterPressed()"))

    spl1=QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    spl2=QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,spl1)
    spl1.addWidget(ptxt1)
    spl2.addWidget(ptxt2)
    spl2.addWidget(ptxt3)

    spl1.resize(500, 500)
    spl1.show()
    spl2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Теперь поясню по шагам.**

`class Test(QtCore.QObject):` - определил свой класс, унаследованный
   от `QObject`. Кто-то же должен принимать сигнал.

В конструкторе только вызвал конструктор базового класса.

Описал действия, выполняемые по срабатыванию сигнала:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def EnterPressed(self):
        print("blabla")
```

Заметьте, т.к. любой слот является ***не статическим*** методом класса, ему необходимо первым (и в этом примере единственным) аргументом передать ссылку на объект, для которого этот метод будет вызван.

В функции `main` создал объект `tst` - экземпляр класса `Test`:

```
tst = Test()
```

Соединил сигнал от нужного объекта `QTextEdit` со слотом объекта `tst`:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ptxt1, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged()"), tst, QtCore.SLOT("EnterPressed()"))
```

Итого имеем, именно то, что вы и хотели.

Comment: а нельзя ли не прибегать к ООП? Т.е. решить задачу без создания класса? Я как раз пытался это сделать.

Comment: @Евгений, поясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, что конкретно вы хотите получить? Чтобы принять сигнал от какого-либо объекта, т.е. выполнить код функции-слота, вам в любом случае необходим экземпляр класса-наследника `QObject`, для которого этот слот и будет вызван.

Comment: получить хочу то, что делает программа, ни больше, ни меньше

Comment: Так сейчас она у вас ничего не делает. Исправил пример.